# Execute MSpec console runner with wildcards in assembly path

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner, mspec

i want to execute mspec console runner with wildcards in the assembly path.

`mspec.exe <.\src\*\bin\Release\*.Tests.dll>`

How is it possible to accomplish this behavior with mspec console runner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible.

Use a build script or a shell (i.e. not cmd.exe) to achieve this. They support expanding globs to actual filenames that you can pass to the runner.